# Stride calculation for Image format YUY2

Tags: android

I am studying Android's YuvImage.java code, http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/YuvImage.java#199:

Why stride for YUY2 is width*2 but stride for NV21 is width?

Here is the code:

```
199    private int[] calculateStrides(int width, int format) {
200        int[] strides = null;
201        if (format == ImageFormat.NV21) {
202            strides = new int[] {width, width};
203            return strides;
204        }
205
206        if (format == ImageFormat.YUY2) {
207            strides = new int[] {width * 2};
208            return strides;
209        }
210
211        return strides;
212    }
```

Comment: Why do I'm reading the opposite of the affirmation in the code condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NV21 format has two planes, one for the luminance and one for the color values. The stride for the first one is *width* (found in the first element of the array) and *width* for the second plane (found in the second element of the array). So it's *width* plus *width*.

In the YUY2 format, the luminance and the color information is interleaved and the stride (the length of a data for a single pixel row) is two times *width* (stored in the only element of the generated array).

Comment: Does that mean stride is always greater than or equal to width of the image? What if the width of image is an odd number or not a multiple of 16, does stride will be rounded up to the closet multiple of 16?

Comment: If you have a black and white image format where each pixel only requires a single bit, the stride would be width / 8, rounded up to the next integer number. Thus, it can be smaller than the width, though not for NV21 or YUY2. I don't think that the stride is rounded up to a multiple of anything. I've never heard of such a requirement for NV21 or YUY2. After all, each luminance or color value is just a single byte or even less. Such rounding rules exist for RGBA and similar formats where each pixel is 4 bytes long.